# Deploying Play2.1-RC1 on heroku gives error

Tags: scala, heroku, playframework-2.0, scala-2.10, playframework-2.1

I encounter this error when I deploy my Play2.1-RC1 based application to Heroku

```
[info] 'compiler-interface' not yet compiled for Scala 2.10.0-RC1. Compiling...
       sbt appears to be exiting abnormally.
         The log file for this session is at /tmp/sbt6398446576215517800.log
       java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:252)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:111)
        at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4.take(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:195)
        at sbt.Execute.next$1(Execute.scala:85)
        at sbt.Execute.processAll(Execute.scala:88)
        ...

            ...
     Error during sbt execution: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space  !  
     Failed to build app with sbt  !     
     Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Play 2.0 - scala app
```

build.properties

```
sbt.version=0.12.1
```

The plugins.sbt file

```
// Comment to get more information during initialization
logLevel := Level.Warn

// The Typesafe repository 
resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"


// Use the Play sbt plugin for Play projects
addSbtPlugin("play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.1-RC1")
```

The Build.scala

import sbt._
import PlayProject._

```
object ApplicationBuild extends Build {

  val appName = "myappname"
  val appVersion = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

  val appDependencies = Seq(
    // Add your project dependencies here,
    jdbc,filters,
    "org.squeryl" % "squeryl_2.10.0-RC2" % "0.9.5-4",
    "postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.1-901-1.jdbc4"
  )

  val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies).settings(
    // Add your own project settings here
  )

}
```

**UPDATE**
Changed JAVA_OPTS and SBT_OPTS from
 `-Xmx384m -Xss512k -XX:+UseCompressedOops`
to
 `-Xmx1024m -Xss512k -XX:+UseCompressedOops`

but same error again.

Comment: I am a bit confused. He OOM error happens at your side or at Heroku's?

Comment: happens at heroku's side

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a PermGen error, try adding:

```
-XX:PermSize=256m
```

It is a known issue, take a look at https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-scala/pull/26 and https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-scala/tree/perm-gen

**UPDATE:**

As @ryanbrainard pointed out, the perm-gen issue has been resolved on the default scala-buildpack, so there is no need to use the specific buildpack mentioned above.

Comment: Ty.Life Saver! used heroku config:add BUILDPACK_URL="https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-scala.g…
…it#perm-gen"

Comment: **The `perm-gen` branch has been merged into `master` and is now the default Scala buildpack on Heroku.**

If you were specifying the `BUILDPACK_URL` to use the branch, you should now return to using the default buildpack:

    heroku config:remove BUILDPACK_URL